# Center of affine W-algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras, w-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional complex simple Lie algebra and $k$ a complex number. Denote by $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ the corresponding affine Lie algebra ($\hat{\mathfrak{g}}=\mathfrak{g}((t))\oplus \mathbf{C} c$ as vector spaces), by $\hat{U}(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ the completion of the universal enveloping algebra of $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ with respect to the topology given by $U(\mathfrak{g}[[t]])t^n$ and by $\hat{U}_k(\hat{\mathfrak{g}}) = \hat{U}(\mathfrak{g}) / (k\cdot 1 - c)$ the level $k$ quotient, where $1\in \hat{U}(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ is the unit and $c\in\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ is the central element.

Let $\chi\colon \mathfrak{n}\rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ be a non-degenerate character (i.e. nonvanishing on simple roots) and $\tilde{\chi}\colon \mathfrak{n}((t))\rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ the character defined by $\tilde{\chi}(x(t)) = \chi(\mathrm{Res}(x(t)dt))$. Recall that the affine $W$-algebra $W_k(\mathfrak{g})$ is defined to be the quantum Hamiltonian reduction $\hat{U}_k(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})//_{\tilde{\chi}}\mathfrak{n}((t))$. For instance, $W_k(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ is isomorphic to the completion of the universal enveloping algebra of the Virasoro Lie algebra at level $c=1-6\frac{(k+1)^2}{k+2}$. I denote by $W_\infty(\mathfrak{g})$ the classical affine $W$-algebra which is isomorphic to the space of functions on the space of $\mathfrak{g}$-opers on the punctured disk.

The Feigin-Frenkel theorem (http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/1991/6/75.extract) asserts that the center of $\hat{U}_k(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ is $\mathbf{C}\cdot 1$ for $k\neq -h^\vee$ (where $h^\vee$ is the dual Coxeter number) and isomorphic to $W_\infty(\hat{^L\mathfrak{g}})$ for $k=-h^\vee$, where $^L\mathfrak{g}$ is the Langlands dual Lie algebra.

Does the affine $W$-algebra $W_k(\mathfrak{g})$ have a nontrivial center?